# How to open second window from main dialog window with pyqt5 and qt designer

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qgis

HI I am trying to develop a plugin. I have used PyQt5 designed to create the Gui.I want to know how to launch a new window after I click on a button.

This is the interface I have created using PyQt5 Designer. Here is the Image link
[image]

Once the Activate button is clicked, Activation key sent dialog box opens as shown in the above image.
Once the OK button is clicked, i need to open a new window as shown
             [image: Login Window]

Here is main ui_dialog.py

```
from .gisedify_support_dialog_login import Ui_Dialog
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
os.path.dirname(__file__), 'gisedify_support_dialog_base.ui'))
class GisedifySupportDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    """Constructor."""
    super(GisedifySupportDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
    # After self.setupUi() you can access any designer object by doing
    # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
    # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
    # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
    self.setupUi(self)

def open_login_dialog(self):
    self.nd = Login_Dialog(self)
    self.nd.show()

class Login_Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Login_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
```

This is my UI_Dialog class

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.resize(400, 300)
    ....
    ....
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")


def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Enter activation key"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login"))
```

I am calling the loginwindow using

```
GisedifySupportDialog().open_login_dialog()
```

The above code does nothing and no error also. Please help me in opening login window when OK button is clicked from main window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def open_login_dialog(self):
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.exec_()
```

Comment: I have a push button named 'login' in new window which is opening, How do i need to trigger click event for the push button in new window?